# In Selenium click middle-mouse button and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

I need to test functionality for a webpage that has the following actions:

- click middle mouse button and scroll middle button up to zoom in
- click middle mouse button and scroll middle button down to zoom out

According to Selenium middle button actions are not supported - [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/).  Is there an alternative way to do this, I am using Javascript. The alternative key for middle button appears to be ctrl-left click, but, I don't know how to then simulate the middle button scroll.

Any help would be grateful.